# How can I add a second private function in Package Body oracle pl/sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

Hey guys I am having an issue where I get an error when I try to add the second private header underneath my first private header.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST IS
PROCEDURE TEST2(VARIABLE1 IN NUMBER, VARIABLE2 OUT NUMBER);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACK BODY TEST IS
FUNCTION PRIVATE1 (VARIABLE1 IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER;
FUNCTION PRIVATE2 (VARIABLE2 IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER;
PROCEDURE TEST2(VARIABLE IN NUMBER, VARIABLE OUT NUMBER)
BEGIN
......
END;
FUNCTION PRIVATE1 (VARIABLE1 IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
........
END;
FUNCTION PRIVATE2 (VARIABLE2 IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS 
BEGIN
.......
END;
END;
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix it?

Comment: And the error is... ?

Comment: Please post an example of the specific construction that isn't working, together with the full error message and line number. Posting a few lines of pseudocode and saying you are "getting an error" will just get you downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
FUNCTION PRIVATE2 (VARIABLE2 IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER; // REMOVE semi colon from here 
IS 
BEGIN
.......
END;
```

Comment: function may not be used in sql.

Comment: In you code you are not calling any function yet, this error comes only when function is used in sql or probably in code, both things are not visible in your code. Its unlikely to get this error during compile time.  In order to get help, you need to share relevant code , and detailed error as it is returned during compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using private function in SQL - this is not supported. In order to use function in SQL you have to define it in the package specification.

We need source code of private1 and private2 functions in order to be able to help more.

[Edit] Here is the example of the package that will fail to compile due to using private function in SQL:

```
create or replace package test_pkg is
end;
/
create or replace package body test_pkg is

  function F1 return number is
  begin
    return 2;
  end;

  function F2 return number is
    lnNumber number;
  begin
    select F1 -- function declared only in the package body
      into lnNumber
      from dual;
    return lnNumber + 1;
  end;

end;
/
PLS-00231: function 'F1' may not be used in SQL
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "F1": invalid identifier
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: If I remove the second private function from the package, the package is created successfully.

Comment: But you obviously need this function, or else you wouldn't have it in the package?The solution is either to remove function call from SQL, declare function in the specification of the package, or change your code in a way that you do not need to call function from SQL

Comment: I guess I will have to go with the second option.